# Discord Link dead?

Tags: craft3

Anyone have the correct invite link for discord? The one on the craft site is invalid.

Here is the one on the website: https://discord.com/invite/uuDFCTX

Comment: Closing since this isn’t about Craft, but a mysterious issue with a link to the Discord server—which seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The link is correct, it works fine here:

[image: Screenshot of the Discord invite screen for the Craft CMS channel]

Make sure that the domain is not blocked on the network level and there isn't anything weird going on with your DNS settings. Maybe clear your browser cache and restart your computer to clear the DNS cache.